# What's wrong with this Arduino code?

Tags: c, arduino

```
// Sketch 4-01 (From the book :) )
int ledPin = 13;
int delayPeriod = 250;

void setup()
{
   pinMode (ledPin, OUTPUT); 
}

void loop()
{
 flash(20, delayPeriod);
 delay(3000);
}

void flash(int numFlashes, int d))
{
  for (int i = 0; i < numFlashes; i ++)
  {

 digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
delay(d);
digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
delay(d);

}
}
```

I'm following the process of this book but my IDE gives me the error "'flash' was not  declared in this scope. Keep in mind, I'm new to programming and this is probably a     basic error. Just trying to modify the blinking LED program.

Comment: You need a [*forward declaration*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) of your `flash` function.

Comment: What about implicit declaration? (depending on which C standard is being followed here)

Comment: What's an implicit declaration?

Comment: Ive done some arduino projects and i never had to use forward declaration :/

Comment: @Tim: that's because the Arduino IDE automatically adds them.

Comment: @Aegis, maybe next time before asking what is the `something` you might not know, it would be better just to Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must place a declaration of the function `flash` before it's being used.

Either place a *prototype* of the function before the `loop` function, like this:

```
void flash(int numFlashes, int d);

void loop
{
    /* .... */
}
```

Or you place the whole function definition before the `loop` function.

And by the way, you have a closing parenthesis to much in the function header. Which of these problems is the real culprit is hard to say without seeing the errors.